# Randomize math symbol in c#

Tags: c#, random

Can someone point me in the right direction to create a checktheanswer method when using a random math symbol? Here's the math problem.

```
Random random = new Random();
        int num1 = random.Next(0, 100);
        Label1.Text = Convert.ToString(num1);

        char[] operators = { '+', '-', '*', '/' };
        char op = operators[random.Next(operators.Length)];
        label2.Text = Convert.ToString(op);

        int num2 = random.Next(0, 100);
        label3.Text = Convert.ToString(num2);
```

How do I write the method to include the random symbols? If it was fixed it would be (I think):

```
    private bool CheckTheAnswer()
{
    if (num1 + num2 == sum.Value)
        return true;
    else 
        return false;
}
```

Comment: Side note: I'd suggest changing the lower bound for `num2` either permanently or just when selecting `/` - otherwise, you're potentially asking someone to divide by zero.

Comment: Instead of checking the answer from CheckTheAnswer(). Calculate the answer using switch case with 'op' variable and store in a answer property while forming question. Then inside CheckTheAnswer() only check the user provided answer match with answer property.

Comment: @Riju - Can you give me a little more information? I can't find what your referencing.

Comment: No one brings the old `DataTable` trick? `private bool CheckTheAnswer()
{ return new DataTable().Compute(String.Format("{0}{1}{2}", num1,op,num2), null).ToString() ==  sum.Value }` :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class MathPuzzle
{

    public string Question { get; set; }

    public double Answer { get; set; }

    public void PrepareQuestion()
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        int num1 = random.Next(0, 100);
        char[] operators = { '+', '-', '*', '/' };
        char op = operators[random.Next(operators.Length)];
        int num2 = random.Next(0, 100);

        switch (op)
        {
            case '+':
                Answer = num1 + num2;
                break;

            case '-':
                Answer = num1 - num2;
                break;
            case '*':
                Answer = num1 * num2;
                break;
            case '/':
                Answer = Math.Round((double)num1 / (double)num2, 2);
                break;
        }

        Question = string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", num1, op, num2);
    }

    public bool CheckTheAnswer(double userProvidedAnswer)
    {
        return userProvidedAnswer == Answer;
    }
}
```

Use the above MathPuzzle class as

```
private MathPuzzle puzzle = new MathPuzzle();
        private void QustionButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            puzzle.PrepareQuestion();
            QuestionLabel.Text = puzzle.Question;
        }

        private void CheckAnswerButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            double userAnswer = double.Parse(AnswerTextBox.Text);
            if (puzzle.CheckTheAnswer(userAnswer))
                MessageBox.Show("Correct");
            else
                MessageBox.Show("Wrong");
        }
```

Answer (score 6):

Create a Dictionary with the operator as the key, and a delegate that executes the operation as a value. Something like this:

```
 var operators = new Dictionary<char, Func<int, int, int>>() { 
      { '+', (a, b) => a + b }, 
      { '-', (a, b) => a - b },
      // Expand as you like: *, /, %, ^, |, &
 };

 // Check
 var correct = answer == operators[operand](term1, term2);
```

You have to include exception handling like divide by zero and/or overflows.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if you are able to include the char directly as Operator, but you could do it this way:

you could change

```
char[] operators = { '+', '-', '*', '/' };
char op = operators[random.Next(operators.Length)];
```

to:

```
char[] operators = { '+', '-', '*', '/' };
int randomOperator = random.Next(operators.Length)
char op = operators[randomOperator];
```

and change

```
if (num1 + num2 == sum.Value)
    return true;
else 
    return false;
```

to:

```
if (randomOperator == 0 && num1 + num2 == Answer)
    return true;
else if (randomOperator == 1 && num1 - num2 == Answer)
    return true;
else if (randomOperator == 2 && num1 * num2 == Answer)
    return true;
else if (randomOperator == 3 && num2 != 0 && num1 / num2 == Answer)
    return true;
else
    return false
```

I hope you get the Idea.